# Vue-svg-loader with Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs3

Tell me, please, why vue-svg-loader works incorrectly with Vue 3 ore what i doing wrong?
I add settings to `vue.config.js`

```
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')

    svgRule.uses.clear()

    svgRule
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader')
  }
})
```

Then i import svg and try add him as component to template

```
<template>
  <YoutubeIcon />
</template>
<script setup>
import YoutubeIcon from '@/assets/Icons/youtube.svg'
</script>
```

And after these steps i get error in console

> Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided
> ('/img/youtube.9fd81e7d.svg') is not a valid name.

Versions:

```
vue: "^3.2.13"
vue-loader: "17.0.0"
vue-svg-loader: "^0.17.0-beta.2" // stable version doesn't work either
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution in issues on github page of vue-svg-loader plugin

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.delete('svg')

    config.module
      .rule('svg')
      .test(/\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/)
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader')
  }
```

Now svg loads correctly

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of searching and trying, I found a solution.

package.json

```
"vue": "^3.2.13",
"vue-loader": "^17.0.1",
"svg-vue3-loader": "^1.0.2"
```

vue.config.js

```
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');
    svgRule.uses.clear();
    svgRule.delete('type');
    svgRule.delete('generator');
    svgRule
      .use('babel-loader')
      .loader('babel-loader')
      .end()
      .use('svg-vue3-loader')
      .loader('svg-vue3-loader');
  },
```

Comment: Been looking for a solution over an hour. Thank you.